# Create a link in Sparx Enterprise Architect (EA) 13's Project Browser

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there a way to insert a link into EA 13's Project Browser? I would be interested in the following 3 sorts of links:

- a link to a HTTP resource
- a link to a diagram present elsewhere in the model
- a link to a folder present elsewhere in the model

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. The browser shows only packages, diagrams and elements. From the latter EA suppresses even a couple (like boundaries, text and more). There is almost no way to customize the browser except for changing the icons of stereotyped elements.